# How to create an ad-hoc NixOS package in configuration.nix

Tags: nix, nixos

I'm trying to use a NixOS package that crashes upon starting. I checked the source, it appears to derive from the .deb release. The application's provider also offers an AppImage that I'd like to experiment with, assuming it might be more reliable.

I'm wonder whether it's possible to make an ad-hoc Nix package within my configuration.nix for testing and temporary usage, prior to making/merging a PR into the official Nix package repo.

I've come across [appimageTools](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#ssec-pkgs-appimageTools-formats), but I can’t find any examples on how to use it within configuration.nix. Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `callPackage`, and then just add it as a value (similar to any other package) to `environment.systemPackages`.

For example:

```
environment.systemPackages = [ pkgs.curl (pkgs.callPackage /path/to/default.nix {}) ];
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the contents of the default.nix inline?  Like to have the contents of my configuration in a single file so its portable.

Comment: You sure can, though I struggle to see a scenario where I can recommend it. Why centralize the building of unrelated projects into a single file? You miss out being able to build each project independently surely? And building an entire Nixos config usually takes much longer.